# Creating different wars from single generic project using maven

Tags: java, maven-plugin, maven-war-plugin

I have a generic type of project based on rest web service .This project contains packages intended for different clients .For example

```
com.package.client1.service
com.package.client2.service
com.package.client3.service

com.package.client1.service.impl
com.package.client2.service.impl
com.package.client3.service.impl
```

This is just an example but there are lots of packages .I want to generate three wars from my generic project that contains the necessary packages that is required for running client1,client2 and client3 wars.

I can create three new projects for client1,client2 and client3 and generate wars .But,if there is way to generate a different wars for different clients from my generic project so that i dont have to create a new project for different clients and paste the necessary packages that is required for that client.

**I have used maven profiling it is creating different wars with resource provided via property file but i also want filtering of packages during war creation** .

**Is there a way to do this? Do maven war plugin supports it? I am using maven ,spring web service.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use maven war plugin while building the file. The configuration can be done to `excludes/includes` classes from package in target/classes while packaging in WAR.

Add the following code to your pom.xml file in order to exclude certain classes:

```
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2</version>
        <configuration>
            <!-- To exclude certain classes -->
            <excludes>**/client2/**/*.class, **/client3/**/*.class</excludes>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Or you can include certain classes only by specifying classes to be included by using `<includes>` tag.

```
<plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2</version>
            <configuration>

                <!-- To include certain classes -->
                <includes>**/client1/**/*.class</includes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

**Note:**

`<excludes>/<includes>` should take a pattern, not a series of `<exclude>/<include>` elements. Multiple `excludes/includes` are seperated by comma `","`

For pattern `**/client2/**/*.class`, first `**/` indicates `com.package` and next `/**/` indicates `service and service.impl` package. You can also add the specific class by changing `*.class` pattern to `classA.class`.

**Output:**
The generated war file contains classes from `com.package.client1.service` and `com.package.client1.service.impl` packages.